# R iterate through data frame and add incremental values to a column based on condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
tdf <- structure(list(indx = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), group = c(1, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1)), .Names = c("indx", "group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
   indx group
1    1     1
2    1     1
3    1     2
4    2     1
5    2     2
6    3     1
7    3     1
```

I want to iterate through the group, and retain the group values for the first index as desiredOutput

For every increment in indx value after the first one, I want to add the max value of the group from the previous indx and want to increment the group values from the second city onwards.

The desired output is like this:

```
    indx group    desiredOutput
1    1     1             1
2    1     1             1
3    1     2             2
4    2     1             3
5    2     2             4
6    3     1             5
7    3     1             5
```

For the sake of clarity I will split the data frame as follows:

```
    indx group    desiredOutput
1    1     1             1
2    1     1             1       To be retained as is
3    1     2             2


4    2     1             3       Second index-the max value of desiredOutput in indx1 is 2                   
5    2     2             4       I want to add this max value to the group value in indx 2       


6    3     1             5       Similarly, the max value of des.out of indx2 is 4
7    3     1             5       Adding the max value to group provides me new values
```

I tried splitting this data frame into a list of data frames and iterating to each one of them.

```
ndf <- split(tdf,f = tdf$indx)
x <- 0
for (i in seq_along(ndf)){
    ndf[[i]]$ng <- ndf[[i]]$group+x
    x <- max(ndf[[i]]$indx) + 1
}
ndf
```

The above code updates the values of the second index but fails when it reaches the third index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the max group values for each index and then calculate the cumulative sums for these groups.

```
library(dplyr)

maxGroupVals <- tdf %>% 
  group_by(indx) %>% 
  summarise(maxVal = max(group)) %>% 
  mutate(indx = indx + 1, maxVal = cumsum(maxVal))
```

Add 1 to index as this is the index to which these max values will be added. Joining the data frames will give you a column with the target increase. Then it's a simple mutate with a conditional statement to handle the index = 1 case.

```
tdf %>% 
  left_join(maxGroupVals) %>% 
  mutate(desiredOutput = if_else(indx == 1, group, group + maxVal)) %>% 
  select(-maxVal)
```

Drop the intermediate calculation column if so desired.

Comment: Thank you....Worked flawlessly on my primary dataset.

Answer (score 2):

To get a running count of the unique indx/group combinations you can simply do (on pre-sorted data):

```
tdf$desiredOutput <- cumsum(!duplicated(tdf))
```

Which gives:

```
  indx group desiredOutput
1    1     1             1
2    1     1             1
3    1     2             2
4    2     1             3
5    2     2             4
6    3     1             5
7    3     1             5
```

Comment: Many thanks...your solution worked too for the given example.  I think your's is the most ingenious solution...couldn't believe how simple this could be....I tried 3-4 times to see if this is working correctly on my larger dataset...it worked flawlessly.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` version 1.0.1 has the function `cur_group_id()` which does exactly what you want. In earlier versions of `dplyr, the` group_indices` function is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
tdf %>% group_by(indx, group) %>%
  mutate(desiredOutput = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider combining the two columns, then convert to factor, then convert to integer. Factor levels are set by `unique` to avoid alphabetical or number ordering but retain order in original data frame.

```
tdf <- within(tdf, {
    tmp <- paste(indx, group, sep="&")    
    new_indx <- as.integer(factor(tmp, levels=unique(tmp)))
    rm(tmp)    
})

tdf
#   indx group new_indx
# 1    1     1        1
# 2    1     1        1
# 3    1     2        2
# 4    2     1        3
# 5    2     2        4
# 6    3     1        5
# 7    3     1        5
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Your solution worked too.  Truly appreciate for a solution using base r....never knew these options...set me thinking.